# App is misconfigured for Facebook Login in Android

Tags: facebook, android-facebook

I am writing an app in which i am *allowing user to do login on fb*, but whenever i am testing my app on mobile getting :  **App is misconfigured for Facebook Login**

I don't know *why i am getting this and how to resolve this issue*?

I have generated **hashkey** and given in my Dashboard also, and i am also using **App ID**
but i don't know where i need to use **App Secret** in my app

Please help me ... to resolve this issue....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very major problem, while work with Facebook SDK and it means which keyhash you have generated that is wrong:

Please follow below steps:

1. Project (RightClick) > Android Tools > Export Signed Application Package
2. Export Android Application : Select Project > Next
3. Create New Keystore > Select Location to Save and give name as Project.keystore > Enter Password | Confirm Password
4. Key Creation- Enter Alias Name, password, Validity, Organisation Name > Next
5. Select path to save apk file, name it as Project.apk > Finish

Now follow below steps:

1. Download OpenSSL and save it into C:/
2. Copy all DLLs files from OpenSSL folder
3. Browse Java bin folder and paste these DLLs here along with keystore (Project.keystore)
4. Now open command prompt and follow this tutorial link:

www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-1